# why index out of range for 'in' line of code?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the code below to remove vowels for any input string:

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    
    for i in range(len(string_)): 
        if string_[i] in vowels: 
            string_ = string_.replace(string_[i],"")
    
    return string_
```

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting an 'index is out of range' error for line "if string_[i] in vowels:"; is it because of the potential mismatch in length of string_ and the list of vowels?

My understanding of the above code is that we will take each character in the input string_ and check if it matches with any of the items in the list vowels, and if it does then execute... Or have I misunderstood the use of 'in'?

Comment: One additional comment, `string_.replace` will replace all instances of `string_[i] with ''` so you're actually shortening your string when you do this.  But you're still iterating over the original length of the string.  Eventually you end up checking say index 10, but you've shortened your string to be shorter than this and you get an index out of range error. This is probably where the `index out of range` error originates.  Solution to the problem has been added below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you're changing the string referenced by `string_` each pass through the loop. So the actual length of the string is changing, while the number of iterations is fixed by the initial length.

For example. Given the string `"rata tat tat"`, would have `len(string_) == 12` when you call it as the parameter for your `range` call. So the loop will iterate `12` times.

First pass:

```py
 string_ == "rata tat tat" and i == 0
 -> string_[i] == "r" 
 -> string_[i] not in vowels
 -> NO OP
```

Second pass:

```py
 string_ == "rata tat tat" and i == 1
 -> string_[i] == "a" 
 -> string_[i] in vowels
 -> string_ == "rt tt tt"
```

Third pass:

```py
 string_ == "rt tt tt" and i == 2
 -> string_[i] == " " 
 -> string_[i] not in vowels
 -> NO OP
```

And the 4th - 8th iterations would also do nothing, but on the 9th iteration your algorithm would have:

9th pass:

```py
 string_ == "rt tt tt" and i == 8
 -> i == len(string_)
 -> string_[i] raises an IndexOutOfRange
```

You'll need to modify the algorithm so it operates instead on vowels, replacing each in the target string.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are dynamically changing the string and hence it's length changes. Instead try this.

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    new_string = ''

    for i string_: 
        if i not in vowels: 
            new_string += i
    
    return new_string
```

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't build up strings like `new_string += i` although it probably doesn't make a huge difference here

Comment: Since you are replacing vowels with "", that means the length of the string decreases by 1 each time and since the for loop traverses till the old length of string, it throws an error that index is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

It's just a matter of how you are replacing them, here is a quick fix:

```py
def disemvowel(string_):
    
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    string_ = list(string_)
    for i in range(len(string_)): 
        if string_[i] in vowels: 
            string_[i] = ""
    
    return ''.join(string_)

def disemvowel2(string_):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
    return ''.join([letter for letter in string_ if letter not in vowels])

s = "asdlkjsadkflja"
print(disemvowel(s))
print(disemvowel2(s))
```

```
In: "asdlkjsadkflja"
Out: "sdlkjsdkflj"
```

Note the second example, by using list comprehension, you can simplify your `disemvowel` function.

## Notes on how each step works:

`''.join(['a','b','c','d'])` joins the characters in the list together placing '' between each character -> `'abcd'`

`list(string_)` converts `'abcd'` to `['a','b','c','d']`

if `string_` is a list, then `string_[i] = ''` sets character `i` to an empty string.